# Some queries under a sustained load of `N` QPS fail due to an INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR error

Tags: soql, rest-api, governorlimits

I have a query with `limit` specified as `500` (user can request a max of 2000 records).

Unfortunately Salesforce, doesn't return the results in one go, but divides the results into multiple pages and sends a `nextRecordsUrl` for next page.

- I assumed that a query with **limit** would return all records in a single response with no pagination.
- This expectation was based on running the same query in SOQL and observing that all `500` records returned in a single response.

**Question**:

How do I force/ensure Salesforce to return all `500` (max 2000) records, **without Salesforce resorting to an implicit pagination and a `nextRecordsUrl`.**

The reason being I have very limited `API users accounts` and under a sustained load of N QPS, some of the requests start to fail due to `INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR`.

Comment: Could you use a custom REST API (written in Apex) for this query (and maybe other queries as required) that doesn't paginate...?

Comment: Are you executing a relationship query (which returns a lot of child records)? That could cause this inconsistent result batch size. For simple queries, I've not observed this problem as far as I can remember.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks that can be one way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify header `Sforce-Query-Options: batchSize=xxxx` as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_queryoptions.htm), but as mentioned in the documentation

> There is no guarantee that the requested batch size is the actual
> batch size. Changes are made as necessary to maximize performance.

Alternatively, you could explore custom REST implementation.

---

**Update (4/20/2022):**
If you have 2 or more long text area fields in the query, then the result batch size will default to minimum i.e., 200, regardless of `LIMIT` clause in the query. This is inline with this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apicalls.htm)

> The batch size will be no more than 200 if the SOQL statement selects
> two or more custom fields of type long text. This is to prevent large
> SOAP messages from being returned.

This is applicable for query via REST API also.

Comment: I don't specify `batchSize` header, the query itself contains the limit clause i.e.  "select col_1, col_2 from foo limit 500"

Comment: Why would Salesforce adjust page size for a query without a `batchSize` header?

Comment: When you use `limit`, ideally SF shouldn't give you results in batches. But I'm not sure if you are executing a simple SOQL or it has nested relationship queries instead. Are you getting batch result within the 500 records? You could try [Get Feedback on Query performance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query_explain.htm) i.e., use `explain` param. However, I'm not sure if that would get you the actual root cause. As noted in the documentation, SF could change batch size to maximize performance.

Comment: The SOQL query is quite simple `SELECT col_1, col_2 from my_table ORDER BY creation_date desc LIMIT 500`. As far as I know there are no child tables involved. By chance are you aware of any documentation, that has details on circumstances, under which Salesforce introduces a batch size?

Comment: Couldn't find any definitive documentation on how Salesforce introduces the batch, but the default size is 2000 and min size is 200. There is one case though where the SOQL batch size will default to 200 (I've tested this out). Check the updated answer. I guess your SOQL query may be falling under this category?

Comment: Thanks, I think this is in line with what I have observed, we do have many long text type fields.